# How to make top flex box row not push down bottom flex box row on hover

Tags: css, flexbox

I have read through the similar issues, but have not been able to see an example that works. Using absolute will make all of the images stack on top of one another. My goal is that when an image in the top row increases in size on hover, it does not push down the images on the bottom row. Thank you!

This is the code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavButton } from '../../atoms/NavButton/NavButton';
import './homepage.css';

export default class Homepage extends Component{

  render () {

    const { history } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="homepage-outer-flexbox">
        <div className="homepage-row-one">
          <NavButton 
            icon="timeline"
            history={history}
          />
          <NavButton 
            icon="me" 
            history={history}
          />
          <NavButton 
            icon="learn" 
            history={history}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="homepage-row-two">
          <NavButton 
            icon="meta" 
            history={history}
          />
          <NavButton 
            icon="projects" 
            history={history}
          />
          <NavButton 
            icon="education" 
            history={history}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```css
.homepage-outer-flexbox { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.homepage-row-one {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
}

.homepage-row-two {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}

.container > img {
    max-width: 65%;
    max-height: 65%;
}

.container > img:hover { 
    max-width: 70%;
    max-height: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
.container > img:hover { 
    transform: scale(1.1); /* Or something*/
}
```

Example:

```css
.img-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.img-container>img {
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .4s ease;
}

.img-container>img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Or something*/
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Why use a redundant `class="img"` on each `img`? You can just target `img` instead of `.img` with your selectors... `.img-container > img { ... }`

Comment: You are right. Normally, I write with scss, but I do not need to use it in this way, but here is the habit of defining a separate class for each item. I updated it.

Comment: Hi there CanUver — ✔ & +1 — when needed I'd still use a different class name than "img", something that indicates _why_ it's not a "plain" image; a class that describes _what_ is special about it. Maybe `<img class="selectable"…>` if it's growing to show what you would be selecting, or `<img class="zoomable"…>` -- have classes describe something about the element(s) they are applied to; a noun like `class="avatar"` or adjective like `class="growable" or a state like `class="selected"`. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: @StephenP you're absolutely right about what you said. Normally, I specify a class name that actually specifies what that element does. The example here is very short and contains few items, so I did not need it. Thank you anyway.